# How do I increase the value of a variable within a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building this rock, paper, scissors game and I've gotten quite far. However, I can't get the final scores to print correctly. No matter the situation, I always get 0 value on total rounds, total wins and ties.

I've been trying to add to these variables within the loop, however, I just cannot seem to figure this out.

```py
import random

# a rock, paper, scissors game

loop = True

while loop is True:
    win = 0
    tie = 0
    lose = 0
    rounds = 0 

    usrchoice = input("Rock, Paper or Scissors? (Quit ends): ") # user makes a choice

    if usrchoice.title() == "Rock":
        pass

    ...

        if computer_choice == "Scissors":
            print("You WIN!")
            win = win + 1
            rounds = rounds + 1


        elif computer_choice == "Rock":
            print("It's a tie!")
            tie = tie + 1
            rounds = rounds + 1


        else:
            print("You LOSE!")
            lose = lose + 1
            rounds = rounds + 1
```

I expect the output to be anything, depending on the user of course, and not just 0. Like this:

```
>>> You played 0, and won 0 rounds, playing tie in 0 rounds.
```

Comment: rounds = 0, wins = 0 and ties = 0, you are setting 0 inside while loop so whatever you add into it, it sets to 0, remove those lines from while loop and place before the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your variables to 0 at the beginning of every loop. Move the variables above the loop to solve this problem.

Eg:

```py
import random

# a rock, paper, scissors game
# foot beats cockroach, cockroach beats nuke and nuke beats foot

win = 0
tie = 0
lose = 0
rounds = 0 

loop = True

while loop is True:
    usrchoice = input("Foot, Nuke or Cockroach? (Quit ends): ") # user makes a choice
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare them before the loop:

```
win = 0
loses = 0 
ties = 0
rounds = 0
while True:
    ...
```

What you are doing is every time the loop starts over again all the variables are set to 0 again. By declaring them before the loop the code will run through and only change the value for them when you increment the by 1 later in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your variables outside the while not inside.